# What is the way to calculate the distance between several objects and to know the name of the object The least distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What is the way to calculate the distance between several objects and to know the name of the object
The least distance in the uinty games editor
I tried in this example

```
public Transform[] allcars;

        for (int i = 0; i < allcars.Length; i++)
        {

            distance =  Vector3.Distance(
              transform.position, allcars[i].transform.position);
            print (allcars[i].name);
        }
```

other example

```
    float ds0 = Vector3.Distance (this.transform.position, allcars[0].transform.position);
    float ds1 = Vector3.Distance (this.transform.position, allcars[1].transform.position);
    float ds2 = Vector3.Distance (this.transform.position, allcars[2].transform.position);
    float ds3 = Vector3.Distance (this.transform.position, allcars[3].transform.position);
     (Mathf.Min(ds0, ds1,ds2,ds3));
```

print (name ??)

Answer (score 0):

Create an variable that stores the distance of your object, and then create an if statement to see if your next object's distance is smaller than the variable's. If it is smaller, override that variable. Then grab the name of that object.

Comment: Building and sorting an entire array for a single point of data is a fairly expensive operation both from a memory and computational budget. If the asker really needs a single item, it would be better to keep a single variable in memory which stores the lowest distance so far, and update that whenever you find a new lowest distance.

Comment: I considered that, but walked away from my computer and finished this up forgetting that. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but there are several objects that need only know the least distance
Of the player and the name of that object